# Admob in ListView not clickable

Tags: android, listview, admob

This is my setup: I have a custom listadapter. The third item is a admob banner. This listview has a onclicklistener which overrides the listener for the admob banner. (This is my first issue). If I set this onclicklistener in comment brackets and click the ad, I get this error: Tried to launch a new AdActivity with a different AdManager. (2nd issue). I hope somebody could help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if you have more than one process running