# Admob: How to perform click at view

Tags: android, listview, admob

How can I perform a click at my admob view?

`admobview.performclick();` doesn't work.

This view is in a list with a `ListItemlistener`, so I have to do this manually

Thanks for your help

Comment: Duplicate : You should maybe improve your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155002/admob-in-listview-not-clickable) than post a new one...

Answer (score 4):

You should ***NEVER*** perform clicks on your AdMob views. That's a direct violation of the terms of use.